# AnimatePresence not working on tooltip despite having valid key and correctly setup animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have a custom tooltip component that looks like this:

```
const Tooltip = ({ visible, message }) => (
    <div className='tooltip-wrapper'>
        <AnimatePresence>
            {visible && <motion.div className='tooltip'
                key={message}
                variants={tooltipFade}
                initial='hidden'
                animate='visible'
                exit='exit'>
                <p>{ message }</p>
            </motion.div>}
        </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
)
```

The animations are like this:

```
export const tooltipFade = {
    hidden: { y: 18 , opacity: 0 },
    visible: { y: 0, opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 0.15, ease: 'easeOut' } },
    exit: { y: 18, opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.15, delay: 1, ease: 'easeOut' } }
}
```

The `visible` prop is true when a mouse enters the element with the tooltip, and changes to false when the mouse exits. While show and hide animations work as expected, the `exit` animation doesn't seem to work, and instead the tooltip instantly disappears. Any ideas?

Edit:

This is how I call the `Tooltip`. One important caveat is that I am mapping an array of items and each has a `Tooltip`. When I then hover over one of them, I set the `showTooltip` state value to the name of the item (called `skill.name`) rather than true, and use that to identify which `Tooltip` to show.

```
const renderList = sortedList.map((skill) => (
        <div className='skill' 
            key={skill.name} 
            alt={skill.name} 
            aria-label={skill.name}
            onMouseEnter={() => setShowTooltip(skill.name)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setShowTooltip(false)}>
            {skill.graphic}
            <Tooltip visible={showTooltip === skill.name} message={skill.name} />
        </div>
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/animatepresencex-0qg5fv?file=/src/Tooltip.js) example. The `Tooltip` component is visible if you hover the `Hover me to make the tooltip visible.` text and disappears after 1 second when you remove your mouse as it is declared in the `tooltipFade`.

The cause of your problem might be that where you call your `Tooltip` component you add the visible flag for rendering.

```
{visible &&
 <Tooltip
    visible={visible}
    message={"Some text"}
 />
}
```

If `visible === false` it hides your component immediately and not allowing the animation to run.

Also something is not clear to me, but I guess you do not need `key` attribute as the documentation states:

```
/**
 * @internal You shouldn't need to use this type since you never see these attributes
 * inside your component or have to validate them.
 */
 interface Attributes {
     key?: Key | null | undefined;
 }
```

My example works without the key attribute as the text is a child of the div.

Comment: Thanks for this Botand. I am not calling `Tooltip` component like that, instead I am actually using a very similar to solution to your code sandbox example. This is how I call it: https://imgur.com/a/w80JvGY (apologies my codesandbox seems to be down :( unsure why ) But it still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I have edited my question to include some more context